# I don't understand the output of enumerate (0, 0), (1,[])

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, output

This is my output:

```
[['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'], ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'], ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
(0, 0)
(1, ['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'])
(0, 1)
(1, ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'])
(0, 2)
(1, ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose'])
```

EXPLAIN THIS TO ME:

**I do not understand what this output means(0,0),(1,[]),(0,1)**,...

When i added the enumeratate to the print_table(), that is when i got the output.

My data is a list of 3 lists so why do i get 5 lines of output?

**EVERYTHING UNDER THIS IS JUST EXTRA INFORMATION**

This is my code:

```
def calculate_widht(data):
    col_width = [0] * len(data)
    word_lenght = 0
    for i, words in enumerate(data):
        # print(i)
        # print(words)
        word_lenght = 0
        for word in words:
            if word_lenght < len(word):
                word_lenght = len(word)               
                col_width[i]= word_lenght
    return col_width


def print_table(width, data):
    print(data)
    for words in enumerate(data):
        for word in enumerate(words):
            print(word)
                
            


def main():
    data = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
            ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
            ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
    start = calculate_widht(data)
    return print_table(start, data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is my exercises:

Write a function named printTable() that takes a list of lists of strings and displays it in a well-organized table with each column right-justified. Assume that all the inner lists will contain the same number of strings.

My output should look like this:

```
   apples Alice  dogs
  oranges   Bob  cats
 cherries Carol moose
   banana David goose
```

Comment: You shouldn't use enumerate in the `print_table` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **understand** the result you're getting you have to look in the docs, in particular [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

> `enumerate(iterable, start=0)`
>
> Return an enumerate object. iterable must be a sequence, an iterator, or some other object which supports iteration. The `__next__()` method of the iterator returned by enumerate() **returns a tuple containing a count (from start which defaults to 0) and the values obtained from iterating over iterable**.

So, your outer `for`-loop

```py
    for words in enumerate(data):
```

produces **tuples** of the form `(int, list)` - your `words`. You can easily verify that by looking at a `print` of `list(enumerate(data))`. That means that in the next level of the looping

```py
        for word in enumerate(words):
```

you are looping over something like `enumerate((int, list))`, **not** over the enumeration of the inner lists, as you seem to expect. Therefore each first `word` has the form `(0, int)` and each second one has the form `(1, list)`. This results in the following printing pattern:

```
(0, 0)
(1, <first list>)
(0, 1)
(1, <second list>)
(0, 2
(1, <third list>)
...
```

---

Your use of `enumerate` doesn't make much sense, it's rather unclear what you want to achieve with it? Seems like you get the data in columns. So you could try something like the following instead:

```py
def print_table(data):
    widths = [max(map(len, column)) + 2 for column in data]
    table = "\n".join(
        "".join(item.rjust(width) for item, width in zip(row, widths))
        for row in zip(*data)
    )
    print(table)
```

First determine the widths of the columns by taking the maximum length of the strings in them, `+ 2` for a buffer to make it look nicer. Then use `zip` to get the rows, right-justify the strings with the resp. `width` and `"".join` them, and then `"\n".join` the so built rows along line breaks.

Result for

```py
data = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
        ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
        ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
```

is

```
    apples  Alice   dogs
   oranges    Bob   cats
  cherries  Carol  moose
    banana  David  goose
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/285477/automate-the-boring-stuff-with-python-character-picture-grid

I though i could do with enumerate like what i could do with range(len()). But could not wrap my head around it, should definitely read more docs.

Answer (score 0):

When you use enumerate(), `words` is a tuple containing the index of the element, then the value.
So when you do:

```py
def print_table(width, data):
     #print(data)
     for words in enumerate(data):
         for word in enumerate(words):
             print(word)
```

You don't behave as expected. You should use a more traditional for loop. Also, you should use `rjust` to right-align the elements.

Your display loop should look like this:

```py
def print_table(width, data):
     for i in range(len(data[0])):
         for j in range(len(data)):
             print(data[j][i].rjust(width[j]), end=' ')
         print()
```

EDIT Note that range(len()) is deprecated because it causes performance issues (at each iteration the length is recalculated)
Also, it's not good Python practice to use this kind of "for" loop. See: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/style/#unpacking

You can use `for index, value in enumerate(...)` instead, or calculate the size only once

Comment: `range(len(...))` is an anti-pattern. It's OK to use enumerate (if the index is actually needed), but preferably with two variables like `for index, value in enumerate(...):`.

Comment: Your **EDIT** is a bit misleading: this isn't a performance-related recommendation, it's more regarding style (how to write _"pythonic"_ code).

Comment: Yes, sorry.  But it's still not efficient to calculate the length every time

Comment: That is why i am using enumerate, cause in 'python' u should not iterate over the index's